# Custom map with draggable pointer for HTML 5

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a jQuery/Angular library to implement a simple map with a static image and a draggable map pointer like google maps in HTML. I would want the x and y coordinates of the pointer in percentage with respect to the static image's resolution.

I am kinna lost.